# Is it possible to automate the follow-up process for tasks in ServiceNow and how does the REST API play a role?

Tags: servicenow-rest-api

**Follow up emails automation for tasks in ServiceNow.**

We have a good junk of problem records and tasks opened, it is a very tiring and cumbersome task to follow up on each problem task with the assigned person. I am looking out for ideas to automate this task which should require minimal human intervention.

I am looking at the possibility to use REST API of SNOW and then may be a program created but while I am writing this it still is under development.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.